# Is it possible to test that provisioning profiles are valid without running a full build?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

We're using fastlane with `match` to build an iOS app on Azure DevOps.

One constant source of pain is provisioning profiles getting broken inadvertently. Dev build is usually okay (failures are dealt with quickly) but a very frequent occurrence is that touching the provisioning profiles breaks some of the less frequently run pipelines, and because they are not run frequently it is discovered at very inconvenient times.

Is it possible to add a step to our "every commit" build that will validate the profiles and fail *quickly*? I can't build every configuration on every commit because it takes too long, but a fail-fast "you broke provisioning profiles" would be amazing.